# jQuery: setup multiple periodicalUpdater

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem on jQuery periodicalUpdater

I set up 2 periodicalUpdater

```
 $.PeriodicalUpdater({
  url : '../../includes/ajax/admin/countorder.ajax.php',
  type: 'text'


 },
   function(data){
        if(data!=0){
            $("#counto").load("../../includes/ajax/admin/countorder.ajax.php");
        }else{
           $("#counto").empty();
       }
   });
   $.PeriodicalUpdater({
      url : '../../includes/ajax/admin/countuser.ajax.php',
      type: 'text'
   },
   function(d){
       if(d!=0){
            $("#countu").load("../../includes/ajax/admin/countuser.ajax.php");
       }else{
           $("#countu").empty();
       }
   });
```

but variable d is getting value of the variable data

How can I set up multiple periodicalUpdater?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be an issue with PeriodicalUpdater -> https://github.com/RobertFischer/JQuery-PeriodicalUpdater/issues/20

Comment: is there any solutions that you know?

Comment: From a little research, I've seen recommendations for this plugin instead: https://github.com/tra/periodic